# How to query my existing Mongodb instead of Inspectdb in Django models

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I have a database that contains such collections as cpu, load, memory. I'm trying to query them, like the example below, I don't need to create my models, my problem is that I can't use the `python manage.py inspectdb` for command to introspect my mongodb.

`models.py`

```
from djangotoolbox.fields import * 
from django.db import models
from mongoengine.django import *
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

class Cpu(DynamicDocument):
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    meta = {
        'collection': 'cpu'
    }
```